# jQuery Animation Thread - Race Condition?

Tags: jquery, animation

**What I want**

I want the user to be able to click on this div, have the animation resize the div for the text box. Once the user clicks on it again, the animation to do the same sequence but in reverse.

**What I have**

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/phx09dw7/15/

**The Problem**

The animation sequence works fine, **until the user would to start rapidly clicking on it**. The animation sequence would screw up, and since I depend on the current height of the div at the time of animation, I believe the two animation sequence will be occurring simultaneously.

**What I've Tried**

As you can see, I tried setting a `animationrunning` variable to prevent the animation from starting while the last one hasn't finished.

```
var animationrunning = false;
$("div.archived_field").click(function () {
var me = $(this);
var check = me.find("input:checkbox");
check.trigger('click');
})

$("input:checkbox").click(function (event) {

if(!animationrunning){
animationrunning=true;
event.stopPropagation();
var me = $(this).parent("div.archived_field");
var id = me.data("field")
var check = me.find("input:checkbox");
var date = me.find("input:text");
if (check.is(":checked")) {



    me.animate({
        height: (me.height() + 52) + "px"
    }, 100, function () {
        date.show(100, function () {
            animationrunning = false;
        });
    })


    //remove from lists to move forward
   } else {



    date.hide(100, function () {
        me.animate({
            height: (me.height() - 52) + "px"
        }, 100, function () {
            animationrunning = false;
        })
    });


    //add to lists to move forward
    }
    }
 });

$("input[type=text]#archive_dates").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**What I think the problem is**

I think some sort of race condition is occurring and the threads aren't pulling the valid value of `animationrunning` - Thus allowing the animations to run at the same time.

**Also**

I've played around with not depending on the height of the div at the time of animation (which reduces the visual bug), but I still have the check box not being checked when its suppose to & vice versa.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `animationrunning` flag works (no race condition), but the problem is that the user can still click on the checkbox (or the div) while the animation is running. When the user does that, the state of the checkbox gets out of sync with the state of the animated elements.

Instead of the flag, you could disable the checkbox while the animation is running.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $checkbox = $(this);

    $checkbox.attr('disabled', true);

    var me = $(this).parent("div.archived_field");
    var id = me.data("field")
    var check = me.find("input:checkbox");
    var date = me.find("input:text");

    if (check.is(":checked")) {
        me.animate({
            height: (me.height() + 52) + "px"
        }, 1001, function () {
            date.show(1001, function () {
                $checkbox.attr('disabled', false);
            });
        })
        //remove from lists to move forward
    } else {
        date.hide(1001, function () {
            me.animate({
                height: (me.height() - 52) + "px"
            }, 1001, function () {
                $checkbox.attr('disabled', false);
            })
        });
        //add to lists to move forward
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nngd77r4/1/)

Another solution would be to stop the animation before animating in the other direction. This would be difficult in your case because you are animating two elements. If you were animating only one, it would be easier.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5685k1h/1/) shows how to use the `.stop()` method to stop the animation, but the code has been changed so only one element is being animated. The hide/show of the text box is no longer animated.